# Unselecting radio buttons using AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, radio-button

I'm creating a Survey app using Ionic and AngularJS 1.x and I am stuck trying to send the correct data when the user submits the form.

When a question has a group of radio buttons (answers), my app marks the answer as "selected" when the user hit one of them (as expected) but if the user hits another option, the previous option stays marked as "selected". So, when the data is submitted, I receive multiple answers in a "radio button question".

[Here´s my code in codepen](https://codepen.io/gusmt66/pen/gwLGwz)

I think I am setting the radio button wrong, here´s the extract of code of it:

```
<ion-radio name="{{q.question}}"
                 ng-if="q.is_simple == 1" 
                 ng-repeat="a in q.answers" 
                 ng-model="a.selected"
                 value="true">
        {{a.answer}}</ion-radio>
```

And then, if the user plays with the radio buttons and hits 2 of them, both options are marked as "selected".

```
"answers": [
    {
      "id": "5",
      "question_id": "2",
      "answer": "Yes",
      "selected": "true",
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "question_id": "2",
      "answer": "No",
      "selected": "true",
    }
```

Could you help me to figure this out? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. You can see that the checkbox questions are working good, but not the radio buttons.

Thank you very much in advance. I'd appreciate any help you could give me.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how a radio button works in angularjs.

You must have the same model for every radio buttons. And then the value will be the one that is selected.

```
<ion-radio name="{{q.question}}"
           ng-if="q.is_simple == 1" 
           ng-repeat="a in q.answers" 
           ng-model="mymodel.thisanswer"
           ng-value="{{a.id}}">
    {{a.answer}}
</ion-radio>
```

**EDIT** Depending of what you want, this could be store in `q.selectedAnswer`. Like this you will have a property in your question with the selected answer.

        {{a.answer}}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. However, I'm generating the radio buttons dynamically with `ng-repeat`, so I'm not sure what exactly to put in `ng-model`. Could you take a look at the codepen and try it putting the correct model? I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance @e666

Comment: Thank you very much @e666 I don't know why I didn't think about it before. I'm new in AngularJS but I'm working hard on learning more everyday. Thanks a lot!